# Numbered copies with exam class

Tags: exam

I'm trying to create an exam with numbered copies in a single file, using the exam package. I've managed to get everything to work, except that the \gradetable contains as many copies of the questions as there are exam copies (NumCopy). Is there any way to reset the grade table?

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{3} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  ...
  % exam content goes here 
  ....
  \gradetable[v][questions] % BUG: contains NumCopy*(number of questions) many entries
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are further counters of class `exam` that need to be reset: `numquestions`, `numpoints`, ...

After the first run, `\label` needs to be disabled to avoid multiply-defined labels. Also `exam` writes to the `.aux` file, which can be prevented by redefining `\PgInfo@write`.

Full example with questions taken from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf) of class `exam`:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ExamResetAfterFirstRun}{%
  \renewcommand*{\PgInfo@write}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{3} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi

  \begin{questions}
    \question[10]
    Why is there air?

    \question[15]
    How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could cuck
    wood?

    \question[10]
    Compute $\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx$.
  \end{questions}

  \gradetable[v][questions]
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: How can I change the language in Italian? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ryuk Commands like `\pointpoints{SingularText}{PluralText}`, `\bonuspointpoints{SingularText}{PluralText}` can be used to translate into Italian.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek How can I change the order of questions in each version?

Comment: @toandhsp If the questions are in separate files, then they can be rearranged by moving the `\input` commands in the master file.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I don't understand. Can you show detaily? I want to change the order of questions in each version and change the order of A, B, C, D in each question. Please help me.

Comment: @toandhsp `\input{A}\input{B}\input{C}\input{D}` or `\input{B}\input{D}\input{A}\input{C}` or `\input{A}\input{D}\input{C}\input{B}`. And `A.tex` to `D.tex` contain the `\question` macro with the question.